# Duck typing with structs in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, types

> For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to simplify the end goal

I'm trying to write a 100% generic PostProvider protocol for Swift.
But, because a 'Post' may contain different information on different platforms, the protocol must be 'generically typed'. Taking a structure as its argument, which defines the structure of any underlying post.

```
struct Post {
    // Only fields required by ALL posts
    var id: UInt64
    var title: String
    var content: String
}

struct WPPost : Post {
    // WordPress posts also have an author
    var author: UInt64
}

struct DrupalPost : Post {
    // Drupal posts also have an author
    var author: UInt64
    // and a 'last updated' timestamp
    var lastUpdated: UInt64
}

protocol PostProvider<TPost : Post> {
    func getPosts() -> TPost[]
    // [...]
}

class WPPostProvider : PostProvider<WPPost> {
    func getPosts() -> WPPost {
        // [...]
    }
}

class DrupalPostProvider : PostProvider<DrupalPost> {
    func getPosts() -> DrupalPost {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

These PostProviders will then be used by other pieces of code.

To make code that uses any PostProvider as reusable as possible, I want any method that takes a PostProvider to be able to typehint what fields MUST be included in the post object.

As such, kinda..

```
func myFunction(provider: PostProvider</*any struct that extends the 'Post' 
                                        struct and contains an 'author'
                                        field of type 'UInt64'*/>)
```

I also wish to do the same thing just with a Post object

```
func myFunction(post: /*any struct that extends the 'Post' struct and 
                           contains an 'author' field of
                           type 'UInt64'*/)
```

*It was pointed out to me by @Alexander that there is no 'struct inheritance' in swift. Let me add that, that is not really the point. This is all pretty much pseudo code anyway. The point is that I need some 'typehinting' method that lets me only 'typehint' the required fields, for some data structure*

Comment: If you need to "extend" your Post and keep type information about it, you should use classes, not structs. There is no such thing as "struct that extends struct" in Swift.

Comment: I added a note at the bottom of my question. Thanks though, I've been thinking that swift had inheritance for structs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duck typing just means "I require a thing that has the following methods." That's a protocol. In Swift, there is no "any struct that extends the 'Post' struct and contains an 'author' field of type 'UInt64'" because there is no such thing as "extends the 'Post' struct." But there absolutely is "any *thing* that has a gettable 'author' field of type 'UInt64'":

```
protocol AuthorProviding {
    var author: UInt64 { get }
}

func thingWithAuthor<T: AuthorProviding>(provider: T) {
}
```

If you want "and also has the Post fields" that just another protocol:

```
protocol Post {
    // Only fields required by ALL posts
    var id: UInt64 { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var content: String { get }
}
```

You of course can make an `AuthorProviding` a type of Post if they go together:

```
protocol AuthorProviding: Post {
    var author: UInt64 { get }
}
```

However, you may also want to keep these separate:

```
protocol AuthorProviding {
    var author: UInt64 { get }
}

func thingWithAuthor<T: protocol<Post, AuthorProviding>>(provider: T) {
}
```

The key here is that you don't need classes and inheritance. You just say what methods you want via protocols. This isn't "typehinting." Swift has strong types. There's no need (or ability) to hint at the types; you just say what they are.

All this said, my experience is that trying to make code too generic from the beginning just makes the code very complicated and (surprisingly) more fragile, and definitely much harder to change. Unless you're writing a framework that you know from the beginning will be used by many diverse groups (like the Swift stdlib), I have found it best to limit generics to the pieces you know you will have a specific need for. It's easy to get into difficult corners with protocols and generics (particularly once associated types are involved), and you find yourself spending a lot of time and code paying for flexibility you will never use. Stack Overflow is littered with difficult questions related to "as generic as possible" code. Some day Swift will likely be a fairly strong generic language, but today it has many sharp edges and surprising corner cases.

Comment: Does this not mean that anything passed to 'thingWithAuthor' needs to _explicitly_ adopt the 'AuthorProviding' protocol? Or is it implicit, just by having the 'author' field it conforms to the 'AuthorProving' type?

Comment: It must be explicit, but you can make it explicit in an empty extension. `extension SomeType: AuthorProviding {}`. This can even be done in another package, so the original author of `SomeType` does not need to know about your protocols.